# How to detect that the content of the WPF Panel was changed?

Tags: wpf, panel

I have a small problem.
I need to detect when a WPF panel content is changed.
For example I changed a property of an Inner button, or drop a control on it....
Thanks

Comment: if you are using a MVVM approach, you should be able to control from your ViewModel class what content is displayed where. This can give you the possibility to listen only to the changes of your bound properties in the VM and not in the View area.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a MVVM approach, but I have more methods that change the content of the panel, like: drop control, delete control, change a control property from property grid, so I want a single "point" to detect changes, and not to implement something everywhere I make changes in the Panel...